npm command on windows gives syntax error every time
I tried to write a script to install the npm_modules in a different location than the current working directory. This was to mirror our workflow where binaries get saved on another drive than the regularly backed up virtual drive where we develop on.
I tried to do this by temporarily setting
npm config set prefix "!targetDir!" where target dir is found beforehand depending on the current dir (to mirror the filepath on the other drive).
I am now aware, that that probably was the wrong command for windows (I now want to use npm install --prefix ./install/here <package> like described in this Q&A https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469515/how-to-npm-install-to-a-specified-directory).
This was the batch script I used when I got syntax error for the first time. I don't remember if the path was correct or not, I just found this by ctrl-z-ing. I first ran it by double klicking. Realizing I've missed the error message I ran it in terminal, this was when I first saw the syntax error
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

SET "currentDir=%cd%"

FOR /f "tokens=3,7 delims=/" %%a in ("%currentDir%") do (
    SET "branchName=%%a"
    SET "repoName=%%b"
)

SET "targetDir=O:\!branchName!\productname\!repoName!"

IF NOT EXIST "!targetDir!" (
    mkdir "!targetDir!"
)

echo RepoName: !repoName!, BranchName: !branchName!, TargetDir: !targetDir!

npm config set prefix "!targetDir!"
npm install
npm config delete prefix

ENDLOCAL

I think since I've used the npm config set prefix "!targetDir!" line in my script, I always get a syntax error whatever I try. If it's impossible for that line to be the culprit, I've tested a few more iterations of the script before realizing npm is not working anymore, which I also could share.
Now I can just type npm in powershell/terminal whatever and it always returns syntax error. It does work though when I use the git bash!
I tried reinstalling nodejs multiple times, I tried updating the npm installation through git bash, I deinstalled nodejs using windows and I manually deleted the nodejs folder in C:/User/Program Files/nodejs. I also temporarily removed the npm folder in %AppData%/Roaming. I also removed npm from path. I checked the called script (npm.cmd) and copied a working version from my private PC. I also tried reinstalling nodejs using chocolatey.
I restarted the PC sometimes in between these steps, but not every time. I always opened a new terminal instance whenever I tried to check if npm is running again.
But I still get the same output:
Syntaxfehler. (or syntax error, I just want to be as precise as possible)

Solution: I went into the %AppData%\Roaming\npm and ran npm directly in there, where it worked. I then used npm config delete prefix and npm is usable again.
What was the problem? I succesfully saved a path in the prefix, but due to my two variables (branchname and reponame) being empty, it looked like O:\projectname. This path was marked as containing an illegal character, even though I'm not sure why. I found out, that the path was set as that, by trying to npm update -g npm in the AppData folder.
I still don't know where this persistent data is located.
